# Magento 2.0 - Render Custom Sales Order Grid Column as Link instead of plain text

Tags: magento2

I managed to add a column on my sales order grid by **adding a column to sales_order_grid table** and added the following xmls respectively:

di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="rahaha_transaction_id" xsi:type="string">sales_order.rahaha_transaction_id</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="rahaha_transaction_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rahaha Txn</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

while I can hardcode the link on the column I added to the sales_order_grid table, is it possible to programmatically convert instead the grid column to show up as an HTML link, instead of plain text?

**UPDATE**
Ok I have managed to find a "potential" solution, the link shows up **but, when you click on the link, it wont open the url but instead go to the Order details page**.  Any of you know how to solve this?  This updated potential solution seems to be better since it also adds a filter to the custom column (which I was supposed to implement next after I have solved this issue).

sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="rahaha_transaction_id" class="Rahaha\AdminSample\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\IsRahahaOrder">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rahaha Txn</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

IsRahahaOrder.php Class

```
<?php
namespace Rahaha\AdminSample\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\CollectionFactory;

class IsRahahaOrder extends Column
{
    protected $_resource;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $escaper;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Escaper $escaper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = "{$item[$this->getData('name')]}";
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added a potiential solution, it still has issues though.  on the line with $item[$this->getData('name')] = "{$item[$this->getData('name')]}";, we can now make it as link, but it cannot be clicked.  clikcing will go to order details page.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<column>` tag to `<actionsColumn>`. So:

```
<column name="rahaha_transaction_id" class="Rahaha\AdminSample\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\IsRahahaOrder">
```

Becomes

```
<actionsColumn name="rahaha_transaction_id" class="Rahaha\AdminSample\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\IsRahahaOrder">
```